# 2001 Subaru Outback - Shaking at Stop

Tags: subaru, vibration, outback

I have a 2001 Subaru Outback.

When I come to a stop at a stoplight I get a nasty vibration.  Seem centered around the passenger front.  We did axles last year but are high mileage drivers.  Axles were Ebay specials.  I also drive the snot out of the car.  Shifting into Nuetral fixes the problem.  I replaced the Torque Converter 3 months ago.  Didn't fix.  No CEL's.  I work on a ton of these so pretty comfortable around the motor and transmission.  Not a big deal to pull one and put it back in for me.  Bad axle again?  I am really struggling to figure this one out.

Thanks in advance!

More Notes:
Flange vibration sound when we are at a stop light.
We also notice small performance issues - it just seems sluggish.

Matt & Jes

Comment: Is the vibration *as you stop* or *after you've stopped* the car?

Comment: @Paulster2 I can tell its doing it as we stop, but its most notably when it is at a complete stop.

Comment: Is your engine turbocharged? If not, I'd suggest you have a vacuum leak in the intake after the throttle body. Just a gut check, though.

Comment: Is the dogbone (pitch stop) in place? There isn't much connecting the engine to the chassis on a Subaru - the dogbone and two 14mm bolts on the subframe. Maybe one of these is loose and letting the engine move. My first thought would have been a misfire, but with no CEL, probably not.

Comment: Not turbocharged.  I can check for a vacuum leak, thanks for the tip @Paulster2.

Comment: Pitch stop is tight @PeteCon.  Rubber bushings look good in it too.  Appreciate the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replaced Axles.  Problem solved.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to provide closure - its appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My money is on one or more bad engine/transaxle mounts.  It would not be the axles if it happens when at a complete stop as they are not moving.

Comment: Another forum when googling  "Vibration When Stopped in Gear Outback" seems to make a pretty good argument for the axle causing just this.  I don't have my mind made up or anything... but I just had them out and the mounts look great.  http://www.subaruoutback.org/forums/66-problems-maintenance/24013-vibration-when-stopped-gear.html

Comment: ^^^ Word to the unsuspecting: First 25 posts of that are  great, and fascinating. You can stop reading around #25, it goes downhill from there, heh.